# PCACompute() does not touch the Matrix<> ouput array parameter

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I'm using the EmguCV 3.0.0 wrapper to OpenCV 3.0.  The EmguCV [`PCACompute`](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.0.0/document/html/c3a0fa3e-8fca-3713-1441-330c090a7234.htm) method wraps the OpenCV [`PCA::operator()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#pca-operator) method.

The following code compiles and runs.  The comments should explain the intent just fine.

```
// Populate the 5 row by 8 column input array (5 samples of 8 dimensions).
// The sample dimensions (columns) vary like this:
//   - low variance: 0, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7
//   - high variance: 2, 3
Matrix<double> input = new Matrix<double>(5, 8);
var r = new Random();
for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++) {
    input.Data[row,0] = r.Next(0, 10);     // low variance
    input.Data[row,1] = r.Next(0, 20);     // low variance
    input.Data[row,2] = r.Next(80, 210);   // high variance
    input.Data[row,3] = r.Next(0, 240);    // highest variance
    input.Data[row,4] = r.Next(20, 21);    // very low variance
    input.Data[row,5] = r.Next(0, 10);     // low variance
    input.Data[row,6] = r.Next(0, 10);     // low variance
    input.Data[row,7] = r.Next(200, 210);  // low variance
}

// create output array for PCACompute()
var eigenvectors = new Matrix<double>(8, 8);

// create *empty* mean array so that PCACompute() calculates its own means
var means = new Mat();

// HERE IS THE MAGIC.
CvInvoke.PCACompute(input, means, eigenvectors);
```

But the magic is broken.  `eigenvectors` is all zeros after all that.  This pretty print code:

```
// print each eigenvector on its own line
for (int vectorIdx = 0; vectorIdx < eigenvectors.Rows; vectorIdx++) {
    string vectorStr = "";
    for(int dimension = 0; dimension < eigenvectors.Cols; dimension++) {
        vectorStr += eigenvectors.Data[vectorIdx, dimension].ToString() + ", ";
    }
    Console.WriteLine("{ " + vectorStr.Substring(0, vectorStr.Length - 2) + " }");
}
```

gives this output:

```
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
```

---

In fact, if I set a member of `eigenvectors` *before* passing it to `PCACompute`:

```
eigenvectors.Data[1,1] = 42;

CvInvoke.PCACompute(input, means, eigenvectors);
```

the pretty print shows that **`eigenvectors` was completely untouched by `PCACompute`:**

```
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
{ 0, 42, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
```

**Is this a bug, or am I doing this wrong?**

Comment: Check if method is void or not? try `eigenvalues = CvInvoke.PCACompute(input, new Mat(), eigenvalues);`. maybe method is creating a new instance and return new `Matrix<double>(8, 8)`.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary, [It's a void returning method](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.0.0/document/html/c3a0fa3e-8fca-3713-1441-330c090a7234.htm).  Thanks though!

Comment: Shouldn't eigenvalues be called eigenvectors in the code?

Comment: @Miki, sorry yes!  I'll change that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite being compatible according to the type system, the 3rd parameter passed to `PCACompute` cannot be of `Matrix<>` type.  Everything works fine if it is a `Mat` type, though!

```
Matrix<double> input = new Matrix<double>(5, 8);
var r = new Random();
for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++) {
    input.Data[row,0] = r.Next(0, 10);     // low variance
    input.Data[row,1] = r.Next(0, 20);     // low variance
    input.Data[row,2] = r.Next(80, 210);   // high variance
    input.Data[row,3] = r.Next(0, 240);    // highest variance
    input.Data[row,4] = r.Next(20, 21);    // very low variance
    input.Data[row,5] = r.Next(0, 10);     // low variance
    input.Data[row,6] = r.Next(0, 10);     // low variance
    input.Data[row,7] = r.Next(200, 210);  // low variance
}

// CHANGE HERE
// Matrix<> was not changed by PCACompute(), so change eigenvectors to a Mat
var eigenvectors = new Mat(8, 8, DepthType.Cv64F, 1);

// create *empty* mean array so that PCACompute() calculates its own means
var means = new Mat();

// Now the magic works fine.
CvInvoke.PCACompute(input, means, eigenvectors);
```

Now `eigenvectors` contains more reasonable data (though it takes different accessor code in the pretty print function)

```
 > eigenvectors.GetValueRange().Max
0.999418
 > eigenvectors.GetValueRange().Min
-0.6326281
```